# Unable to remove error state from WPF DataGrid Cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF datagrid using the WpfToolkit version 3.5.40128.1
For one cell I raise a PropertyChanged event that the viewmodel has a listener for, and determines if the value is duplicated to the other values.  If it is duplicated, a state is set on the object and the cell is put into an error state.

So a user can enter Priority in the first record to 2 and the second field to 2 and the second value is in error.

When the user changes the error field all works as expected.
When the user changes the first '2' to 1 the second field is no longer duplicated and the flag is cleared.  However, no matter what I do, the field remains in error.  I have tried the following:

1) I added a PropertyChanged event call on the field even though it is in an ObservableCollection.  This caused a regular check for duplicate values but did not remove the red outline.
2) I added event styles for both ValidationErrors==true as well as ValidationErrors==false.  This sounded hopeful but it only clears the tooltip it does not clear the red outline.
3) I added a PropertyChanged call on the state boolean when it's value changes.

Playing with the field myself manually in the form, if I enter and exit the field it remains in error.  If I enter the field and re-enter '2' the error state goes away.

I'm at a loss now as to what else to do!  Any suggestions on additional things to try would be helpful.

Below is the style and definitions of the datagrid.  Priority is the only field being validated.

```
  <!-- style to apply to DataGrid TextBlock  -->
  <Style x:Key="DataGridTextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration"
                  Value="20000"/>
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="false">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip"
               Value=""/>
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>

  <!-- style to apply to DataGrid CheckBox  -->
  <Style x:Key="DataGridCheckBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration"
                Value="20000"/>
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="false">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                Value=""/>
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
  <!-- style to apply to DataGrid TextBox in edit mode  -->
  <Style x:Key="CellEditStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration"
                Value="20000"/>
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="false">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip"
               Value=""/>
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
  <!-- style to apply to DataGrid Checkbox in edit mode  -->
  <Style x:Key="CheckboxEditStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration"
                Value="20000"/>
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="345*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="88*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="50" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  Margin="2,2,2,0" Header="Region Selection" 
                    BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
      <Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical" Height="120" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White">
          <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="5,5,5,5" Height="101" >
            <wpftk:DataGrid x:Name="SegmentGrid"
                              IsEnabled="True"      
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                              Height="90" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding SegmentList}"       CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" >

              <wpftk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <!--  The Region Name Column -->
                <wpftk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" 
                                  Width="265" 
                                  Binding="{Binding RegionName}" />
                <!--  The Priority Column -->
                <wpftk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Priority" Width="60">
                  <wpftk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                      <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DataGridTextBlockStyle}" 
                             Text="{Binding Priority, Mode=TwoWay,  
                               ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
                               UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                  </wpftk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <wpftk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                      <TextBox>
                        <TextBox.Text>
                          <Binding Path="Priority"  
                               UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" 
                               ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"  >
                          </Binding>
                        </TextBox.Text>
                        <TextBox.Style>
                          <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource CellEditStyle}" />
                        </TextBox.Style>
                      </TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                  </wpftk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </wpftk:DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <!--  The Write To Cartridge Column -->
                <wpftk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Write To Cartridge" Width="80">
                  <wpftk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                      <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource DataGridCheckBoxStyle}" 
                             IsChecked="{Binding WriteToCartridge, Mode=TwoWay, 
                               ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
                               UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                  </wpftk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <wpftk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                      <CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                          <Binding Path="WriteToCartridge"  
                               UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" 
                               ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" 
                               ValidatesOnExceptions="True" >
                          </Binding>
                        </CheckBox.IsChecked>
                        <CheckBox.Style>
                          <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource CheckboxEditStyle}" />
                        </CheckBox.Style>
                      </CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                  </wpftk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </wpftk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
              </wpftk:DataGrid.Columns>
            </wpftk:DataGrid>
          </ScrollViewer>
        </StackPanel>
      </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
```

Comment: First thing you do before asking a question is create a [mcve] that isolates exactly what you are trying to do without any distractions of other code. If this doesn't immediately show you what is wrong (this happens often and is one of the benefits of doing this!), you use this code to ask a question. Without any code, we can't tell you where you're going wrong.  Go do it now, and [edit] your question to add it in, if you still can't get it to work.

Comment: Try to inspect `Validation.Errors` of the cell with some WPF inspector like WPF Snoop. I believe an error still there. Also I highly recommend to go away from `IDataErrorInfo` interface (where validation is tightly bound to property changes notification) and use `INotifyDataErrorInfo`.

Comment: @Maxim The INotifyDataErrorInfo came out in 4.5 and we are not moving to the 4.0 framework for a while yet.  We are still bound by 3.5.

Comment: @Will -- This question is perfectly legal or at least has been the past several years I've written and answered question on this forum!!!!!!  I indicated my issue and I indicated my attempts to fix it.  It has never been a REQUIREMENT to do a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable" example EVER.  To request my question be closed is asinine.  And if someone asks to see the code I will gladly add the code.   However the U.S. Government does not pay us to write code in a new solution so you can copy and play with it.  They pay us to write a solution and get answers to issues we run.

Comment: Okay, completely disregard any advice I offered for your benefit, and completely ignore the fact that the MCVE link is literally hosted on Stack Overflow, which *just might suggest to you* that it's an important step to getting good answers to your question quickly.  You keep on being you, guy.  Good luck, and good day.

Comment: @Will you did NOTHING for my benefit.  You only did for your own feeling of power trying to shut down a valid question!

Comment: @MAXIM in the edit styles you can see that if Property="Validation.HasError" Value="false" that the tooltip gets cleared.  I'm finding that this style is getting triggered because once it leaves the IsDuplicate state the tooltip no longer pops up.  But the red outline remains.  Very frustrating and most likely another quirk of the DataGrid.  Hoping someone has encountered this before and solved it.

Comment: ***I SAID GOOD DAY!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to expose a new method inside the object for INotifyPropertyChanged.
This allowed us to examine all of the objects in the array, and when we changed the value we called it from the object rather than from the viewmodel.  This caused the automatic finding and clearing of any object that was duplicated within the array.